# How can I verify on download that a site's SSL cert is for a host I trust?

Tags: linux, certificate, https

### Generally

I want to be able to make an HTTPS connection to a site, and while negotiating the SSL check that:

1. The cert is in every way valid for the host listed on the cert (unexpired, signed by trusted CA), and
2. The cert is for a host I specify (i.e. I may be connecting via HTTPS to example1.com, but I just want to verify that the cert used by example1.com is valid for example4.com because I trust example4.com has not been compromised).

### Specifically

There's a site affiliated with redhat which uses a cert valid for *.redhat.com, but which is not under the redhat.com domain. In every other way this cert is valid (i.e. it is issued by a  trusted CA, it hasn't expired, and I am 99.99% sure it isn't stolen- although, if it were, that would mean redhat was compromised, so I'd have bigger problems), and I want to download an RPM module from this site, while (hopefully) guaranteeing I haven't been MITM'd.

So, I want to download something from the redhat-affiliated example.com while verifying that the site I'm connecting to is actually using a valid redhat cert.

### Things I've already tried:

`curl` -- the closest curl has to this functionality is [this option flag](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-k), which just disables all certificate authentication, which is *not* what I want, and

`wget` -- just has the argumentless `--no-check-certificate` option, which is equally unhelpful.

According to the libcurl documentation, I could use [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSSLCTXFUNCTION), which looks promising, but mentions that it requires I have "... a non-trivial amount of knowledge of the openssl libraries", which I demonstrably don't possess. I can program in C or Python or whatever, although what would be most helpful is (in descending order of preference):

1. a bash / sh solution using only command-line applications which usually ship with RHEL-based distros,
2. or a solution using a commmon scripted language (Python, Perl, Ruby, etc.) with no library dependencies which require download,
3. or a solution using a nonscripted language (C/C++, Java, Haskell, etc.) which again doesn't require any library downloads.

Comment: Check the certificate chain

Comment: @Ramhound That isn't quite the issue; it doesn't lend itself well to a description short enough for the title, unfortunately. The issue is that the cert is valid for a diffferent host, but I want to accept that, anyway. But from the command line, not a browser.

Comment: You say the cert is for *.redhat.com but you never say what domain you are actually connecting to.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I didn't think it would be relevant. The omission was intentional- unless you work for redhat and know for a fact that cert isn't used on other domains, in which case there may be cause for concern.